# Can't get objectAnimator working with xFraction

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, fragmenttransaction, objectanimator

I'm trying to animate a `slide-in/slide-out` animation between `Fragments`. I know there're tons of similiar question out there on *StackOverflow*, but believe me - I tried all of them and none is working.

Following my code (basically taken from similiar questions):

#### Custom Layout

```
public class SlidingFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    public SlidingFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SlidingFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public float getXFraction() {
        final int width = getWidth();
        if (width != 0) return getX() / getWidth();
        else return getX();
    }

    public void setXFraction(float xFraction) {
        final int width = getWidth();
        setX((width > 0) ? (xFraction * width) : -9999);
    }
}
```

#### Fragment Transaction

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_enter_right, R.animator.card_out_left);
ft.replace(R.id.quiz_container, CardFragment.newInstance());
ft.commit();
```

#### Object animator

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:propertyName="xFraction"
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="0.0"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```

#### Layout file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.my.package.views.SlidingFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/quiz_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Other views -->

</FrameLayout>
```

So when I'm running this code nothing happens. The Fragments get **replaced** but **without an animation**.
What am doing wrong?

**Note:** If I'm running the animation with `"x"` instead of `"xFraction"` and changing the values to let's say `from:1280 to:0` it's working. Unfortunately this isn't a solution for me, since I need a *"percentage value"* because of the broad range of display resolutions.

---

### Solution

Thanks to [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) who led me to the solution.  I always thought that the container of my Fragment needs to implement the getXFraction()/setXFraction() method. But that's not true. You're Fragments layout needs to implement `getXFraction()/setXFraction`. 
So basically I changed my Fragment-Layout from something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:prefix="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="40dp"
    prefix:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<!-- Content -->
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

to:

```
<com.my.package.views.SlidingFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:prefix="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        prefix:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<!-- Content -->
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</com.my.package.views.SlidingFrameLayout>
```

Comment: setXFraction and getXFraction should be defined in the root view:  the view you return from onCreateView,  test it by removing root FrameLayout

Comment: That's something I tried as well, unfortunately the problem remains. I just edited my question.

Comment: in this case replace objectAnimator with animator in xml file, override Fragment.onCreateAnimator, load your animator and setup update listener

Comment: I've just tried this. Everything gets called properly though nothing has changed. And honestly saying I don't know what's the purpose of this?!

Comment: is your listener called or not?

Comment: It's called, please see my edit / additional note. Btw: Thanks so far for your efforts.

Comment: no no no,  your "animator" is actually ValueAnimator,  so use addUpdateListener,  not addListener

Comment: Ok, just changed that (see edited post). `onAnimationUpdate` is called as well. Isn't it strange that the `getXFraction` method isn't called ever?

Comment: it is called, on the root view in your hierarchy,  in your case CardView,  what is strange you say you dont have a CardView as a root in your Fragment

Comment: your previous edit was ok: use AnimatorInflater but cast the result to ValueAnimator

Comment: Now I'm feeling kinda stupid. The CardView is actually the root-view of my `CardFragment`. I just wrapped the `CardView` inside my `SlidingFrameLayout` and now it works flawlessly. Would you mind posting this as an answer so that I can accept it? **Note:** I always thought that the container of my Fragment needs to implemented the `getXFraction()/setXFraction()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setXFraction and getXFraction should be defined in the root view: the view you return from onCreateView, in your case custom CardView

Answer (score 3):

since above code listings are only partial, I thought I'd share with you a complete working example. It works as outlined in the question.

Pressing the button toggles between 2 fragments A and B (by slide animation right to left). The fragments are just stupid text (AAAAAA and BBBBB) with different backgrounds.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.slidetrans;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    boolean showingA = true;
    Button button;

    A a;
    B b;

    private void incarnate(FragmentManager fm){
        int layoutId = R.id.frame;
        boolean fragmentWasNull = false;
        Fragment f = fm.findFragmentById(layoutId);
        if (f == null){
            if (showingA){
                f = a = new A();
            } else {
                f = b = new B();
            }
            fragmentWasNull = true;
        }
        if (fragmentWasNull){
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(layoutId, showingA ? a : b,  "main").commit(); 
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        incarnate(fm);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.in, R.anim.out);
                transaction.replace(R.id.frame, showingA ? new B() : new A()).commit();
                showingA = !showingA;
                button.setText(showingA ? "slide in B" : "slide in A");
            }
        };
        button.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }
}
```

LL.java

```
package com.example.slidetrans;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class LL extends LinearLayout {

    public LL(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LL(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public float getXFraction() {
        final int width = getWidth();
        if (width != 0) return getX() / getWidth();
        else return getX();
    }

    public void setXFraction(float xFraction) {
        final int width = getWidth();
        float newWidth = (width > 0) ? (xFraction * width) : -9999;
        setX(newWidth);
    }
}
```

main.xml (layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="slide in B" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

a.xml (layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.slidetrans.LL xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#00FF00"
>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/aText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />

</com.example.slidetrans.LL>
```

b.xml (layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.slidetrans.LL xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFF00"
>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="BBBBBBBBBB"
    />

</com.example.slidetrans.LL>
```

in.xml (anim)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
    android:duration="500"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:propertyName="xFraction"
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="0.0"
    android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

out.xml (anim)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
    android:duration="500"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:propertyName="xFraction"
    android:valueFrom="0.0"
    android:valueTo="-1.0"
    android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 1):

The example provided by @mathheadinclouds worked for me using "R.animator.in" instead of `R.anim.in` in the line:

```
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.in, R.anim.out);
```