# How to resolve when providing Layout left margin programmatically to a View / Viewgroup (For Animation), View getting shrinking

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

How to resolve when providing Layout left margin programmatically to a View / Viewgroup  (For Animation)

When View reaches, view's **Y** pos to screen width(For example 240), View got shrinked.

View's X position is still moving but Y position not moving(if it reaches view's Y pos to screen width) so the view was shrniked.

i tried with setting width for that view (i.e) `getLayoutParams().width = width // screen width`
which is not working

Comment: Im using ValueAnimator for animation which gives a values between start and end position from that i will update the View's X position. i will drag a button so animation will perform (drag like right left look like Notification bar animation when open)

Answer (score 0):

We **can't use** `leftMargin` as we will do in Web. The view is setted to match_parent, android try to keep all content viewable.

We have to use **translation** so. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854940/android-using-objectanimator-to-translate-a-view-with-fractional-values-of-the) is an answer. Moreover, it's more flexible.

I've also used it in one app, see :
- [my custom view](https://github.com/HugoGresse/TweetyHunting/blob/f036f163bd2d16ae122df154afbe6abd916d77a1/app/src/main/java/fr/xjet/tweetyhunting/view/CustomCardView.java)
- [my animator xml](https://github.com/HugoGresse/TweetyHunting/blob/f036f163bd2d16ae122df154afbe6abd916d77a1/app/src/main/res/animator/slide_out.xml)
- [java code](https://github.com/HugoGresse/TweetyHunting/blob/master/app/src/main/java/fr/xjet/tweetyhunting/TweetingActivity.java#L340)