# Slide in from the bottom animation using Animator in Android

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator, animator

I am trying to achieve this with `Animator`, instead of `Animation`, but I don't know how and I could not find an answer that works around StackOverflow:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="250"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

Is it possible to make this with `Animator`?

Comment: When using the `animator` directory you have to use `PropertyAnimations` and not `ViewAnimations` - in other words your `<translate ... />` node isn't valid. To achieve the desired effect see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854940/android-using-objectanimator-to-translate-a-view-with-fractional-values-of-the)

Comment: Hello, @reVerse o/. This is just an example using `Animation` of what I want, but using `Animator` :)

Comment: Get it. I think the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854940/android-using-objectanimator-to-translate-a-view-with-fractional-values-of-the) should make it clear what's necessary. Unfortunately the framework doesn't provide anything out of the box but doing it on your own should be kinda easy.