# Android set percentages for object animator

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying out object animators and I am confused as to how I can set the values as percentages.

Using old animation I can just do:

```
inside anim/translate.xml
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="80%p"
    android:duration="500"/>
```

but when I do:

```
// inside animator/translate.xml
<objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="TranslationX"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="80%p"
    android:duration="500"/>
```

I get the error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "80%p"`

I tried looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854940/android-using-objectanimator-to-translate-a-view-with-fractional-values-of-the/11015834#11015834) and added this

```
<objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="xFraction"
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="0.8"
    android:duration="500"/>
```

but it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible to do it via xml so need to change set the percentages programatically

```
val display = windowManager.defaultDisplay
val size = Point()
display.getSize(size)
val displayWidth = size.x * 0.8f

val objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "translationX", 0f, displayWidth)
objectAnimator.duration = 500
objectAnimator.start()
```